# Why do I get “`TypeError`: `flattenDeep(...)` is not iterable”, if I don’t use the initial value for `reduce`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce, flatten

When I write the function below, it throws the below error:

```
const flattenDeep = (arr) => Array.isArray(arr)
  ? arr.reduce( (a, b) => [...flattenDeep(a), ...flattenDeep(b)])
  : [arr]

const a=flattenDeep([1, [[2], [3, [4]], 5],[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]])
console.log(a);
```

[image: error message]

And when I change it, it works. Why can it run after adding the initial value `[]`?

```
const flattenDeep = (arr) => Array.isArray(arr)
  ? arr.reduce( (a, b) => [...flattenDeep(a), ...flattenDeep(b)], [])
  : [arr]

const a=flattenDeep([1, [[2], [3, [4]], 5],[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]])
console.log(a)
```

This works fine, and prints `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get this error is because, at the beginning, `flattenDeep(b)` will be called with `b === [[2], [3, [4]], 5]`. This, in turn, will call `flattenDeep(a)` with `a === [2]`.

`Array.isArray([2])` is `true`, so `[2].reduce((a, b) =>`…`)` without an initial value will be called. `reduce` takes into account the *initial value, if any*, then *all other array elements*, as arguments for `a` and `b`, where `a` accumulates the return values and `b` is the *next value*.

The result of calling `reduce` on an array with a single value (plus the initial one at the beginning) is *that single value*. In other words, the function body `[...flattenDeep(a), ...flattenDeep(b)]` isn’t executed at all, no array is ever created. Just the array’s first element, `2`, is immediately returned.

So `flattenDeep([2])` is `2` which is not iterable.

Adding the initial value `[]` causes `reduce` to *always* return an array, even if it’s just that empty one. And of course, an array is always iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You should supply an initial value when using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

**Syntax**

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

**Parameter**

`initialValue` (Optional)

Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling `reduce()` on an empty array without an initial value is an error.

**How reduce() works**

Suppose the following use of `reduce()` occurred:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return accumulator + currentValue;
});
```

The callback would be invoked four times, with the arguments and return values in each call being as follows:

```
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
|   callback   |  accumulator |  currentValue | currentIndex |      array      | return value |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| first call   |           0  |            1  |           1  | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] |            1 |
| second call  |           1  |            2  |           2  | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] |            3 |
| third call   |           3  |            3  |           3  | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] |            6 |
| fourth call  |           6  |            4  |           4  | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] |           10 |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

The value returned by `reduce()` would be that of the last callback invocation (10).

You can also provide an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in lieu of a full function. The code below will produce the same output as the code in the block above:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce( (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue );
```

If you were to provide an initial value as the second argument to reduce(), the result would look like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
    return accumulator + currentValue;
}, 10);
```

..

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
|   callback   | accumulator | currentValue | currentIndex |      array      | return value |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| first call   |         10  |           0  |           0  | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] |           10 |
| second call  |         10  |           1  |           1  | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] |           11 |
| third call   |         11  |           2  |           2  | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] |           13 |
| fourth call  |         13  |           3  |           3  | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] |           16 |
| fifth call   |         16  |           4  |           4  | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] |           20 |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

The value returned by `reduce()` in this case would be 20.

Hope this resolve your question

Comment: The question was _why_ the initial value, that the OP already uses, resolved the problem.

Comment: `You should supply an initial value when using Array.reduce()`,your words enlightened me. Thank you.